# What is wrong with this drive?

Tags: disk-utility, carbon-copy-cloner

I've tried to create this partition and use Carbon Copy Cloner to copy over everything from one Mac. However, it shows this error on another Mac when I launch Disk Utility and try to repair it:

[image]
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1):

In technical terms it is "messed up too much" for disk utility to handle. You now have two choices. Do as it suggests, back up and reformat or use a third party disk utility that *might* fix the issue.

I'd do the latter but then I always have an up to date copy of diskwarrior already on hand. There are other disk repair utilities, that one is my personal favorite YMMV.

Comment: I second the recommendation of DiskWarrior; it's the best tool I've used for problems like this. But if you have the space on another drive, backing up and reformatting is a good option too.